# Representation of an operator in another base

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-algebras, quantum-mechanics

We have the following operator

$\hat{H} = a|u_{1}\rangle \langle u_{2}| + a|u_{2}\rangle \langle u_{1}|$, with a = real constant and $|u_{i}\rangle $ an orthonormal base.

The matrix representation, H, of this operator in the $|u_{i}\rangle $ base is

\begin{pmatrix}
0 & a\\
a & 0
\end{pmatrix}

the eigenvalues are a and -a, and the corresponding orthonormal eigenvectors are $|\phi_{1}\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}$(1 1) and $|\phi_{2}\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}$(1 -1).

We want to find the matrix representation, H', of the operator $\hat{H}$ in the base $|\phi_{i}\rangle $.

So, I know we can do that multiplying matrixes like H' = SHS*, where S is the change of basis matrix with S$_{mn}$ = <u$_{m}$|$\phi_{n}$>. But our professor told us he didn't want us to do it that way, that there is a faster one, but I can't seem to find it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, $\hat{H}|\phi_1\rangle=a|\phi_1\rangle$ and $\hat{H}|\phi_2\rangle=-a|\phi_2\rangle$ thus the matrix of $\hat{H}$ in the basis $|\phi_i\rangle$ is simply
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
a & 0 \\
0 &-a
\end{pmatrix} $$